# Storm Nimbus is not working

Tags: apache-storm

I'm new to Apache Storm and I'm currently working on a project which uses storm. While trying to understand the basics of storm, I came across nimbus and supervisors. I started setting up a remote cluster. I edited the storm.yaml file and setup the nimbus and zookeeper to localhost. I tried running my nimbus, zookeeper in my local machine. I started nimbus using "storm nimbus", but nimbus is not started whereas my zookeeper is actively running. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mff1.png)I have the screenshot of what I get.

Can somebody help me in sorting out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the directory where you have installed your `storm` go to `bin` folder and run:

```
storm nimbus
```

reference image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the start command from the bin directory of the storm installation directory.

Navigate to the bin folder inside storm installation folder and then run "storm nimbus".